# Find a number $c$ so that $x$ and $x + cy$ are uncorrelated.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Suppose that for the random variable X,Y, we have $E(X) = 2, E(Y) = 1, E(X^2) = 5, E(Y^2) = 10, \text{and } E(XY) = 1$.
>
> a) compute $Corr(X,Y)$
>
> b) find a number c so that $X$ and $X + cY$ are uncorrelated.

So part a) is pretty straightforward: $Corr(X,Y)=\frac{Cov(X,Y)}{\sqrt{Var(X)Var(Y)}}=\frac{E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)}{(E(X^2)-(E(X))^2)(E(Y^2)-(E(Y))^2)}=\frac{1-2*1}{\sqrt{(5-2^2)(10-1^1)}}=-\frac{1}{3}$

How to approach part b)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

Let the following 
\begin{align}
Cov(X, X+cY) &=Cov(X,X)+cCov(X,Y)=0
\end{align}

Solve for $c$.

Comment: so $Cov(X, X+cY) =Cov(X,X)+cCov(X,Y)=Var(X)+cCov(X,Y)=1+c(-1)=0 \Rightarrow c=1$ Thanks.